# Referring Local JS file dynamically in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular8

I'm trying to refer js files located in my project on selecting a page in menu.

I'm getting error that the JS is not found. The below is the error message.
http://localhost:57158/Js/flowchart.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Kindly suggest

[image: Here is my code]

Comment: If you are using a bundler like WebPack, then you have to tell the bundler where the files are. You cant just create a script and reference them, because the script-files won't be in the dist folder

Comment: @Tracer69, can you elaborate more, I'm a newbie to angular

Comment: ``externalScripts.forEach(script => require(script))``
or something like this.